# Open Password Protected zip file with python

Tags: python, brute-force, password-recovery

I am trying to open a protected zip file I know for a fact that the first 5 characters are Super and the password is eight characters long with no numbers or symbols I am using this code in python to help me but it is not working can anyone help?

code:

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import time

# Function for extracting zip files to test if the password works!
def extractFile(zip_file, password):
try:
    zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
    return True
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit(0)
except Exception as e:
    pass

# The file name of the zip file.
zipfilename = 'planz.zip'
# The first part of the password.
first_half_password = 'Super'
# We don't know what characters they add afterwards...
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)

# For every possible combination of 3 letters from alphabet...
for c in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3):
   # Add the three letters to the first half of the password.
   password = first_half_password+''.join(c)
   # Try to extract the file.
   print("Trying: %s" % password)
   # If the file was extracted, you found the right password.

   if extractFile(zip_file, password):
       print('*' * 20)
       print('Password found: %s' % password)
       print('Files extracted...')
       exit(0)

# If no password was found by the end, let us know!
print('Password not found.')
```

Comment: Not working meaning you get an error, if so provide the error?

Comment: it is working but it is printing Password not found

Comment: You are not checking uppercase letters

Comment: could be how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hy man! Basically, you can just append the alphabet variable to include the uppercase letters, the password is a play on superman, If I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that 
if extractFile(zip_file, password):
is also true for wrong passwords in many cases. (see:https://bugs.python.org/issue18134) It then leaves an "unziiped file" with length 0 or some bytes.

You have to check if the output file is the right size.

for example by finding out the size of the first file in zip

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)

firstmember=zip_file.namelist()[0]
firstmembersize=zip_file.getinfo(firstmember).file_size
```

and later

```
if os.path.getsize(firstmember) == firstmembersize:
```

and dont forget to delete the wrong sized file after checking to give way for the next try ...